# Random Generator with Strings ? (Java)

Tags: java, string, random, generator

**Hello Guys**

i learning Java and i will programm a random generator but with strings... I mean as Example

User give the Strings: Ass, Pet, Dog
Now The Generator use the Strings to random connect the words.

Now i have:

```
public void buttongeneratedClicked()
{
        String ex1 =jTextField1.getText();
        String ex2 =jTextField2.getText();
        String ex3 =jTextField3.getText();
        String ex4 =jTextField4.getText();
        String ex5 =jTextField5.getText();
        String ex6 =jTextField6.getText();
        String ex7 =jTextField7.getText();
        String ex8 =jTextField8.getText();

        if(wordwish == true && randompasswd == false) {
            output.append(ex1 + ex2);
            output.append("\n");
            output.append(ex1 + ex3);
            output.append("\n");
            output.append(ex1 + ex4);
            output.append("\n");
            output.append(ex1 + ex5);
            output.append("\n");
            output.append(ex1 + ex6);
            output.append("\n");
            output.append(ex1 + ex7);
            output.append("\n");
            output.append(ex1 + ex8);
            output.append("\n");
        }
    }
```

And i know that is a bad Solution. How can i do that the Program work by self to connect all Strings together and when all strings are connected with the other strings he ending. I dont need full solution but i dont find helpless links to this. I Hope anybody can help me ^^ Greetz

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to randomly connect multiple Strings together using `Random`, `ArrayList`, and `StringBuilder`:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Example class for how to randomly connect disparate strings.
 */ 
public class StringRandomizer
{   
    /**
     * Method that randomly connects some strings together.
     */
    public static String getRandomString()
    {    
        Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // add all of your strings to the list
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");

        // Build your return string
        while(!list.isEmpty())
        {
            //this line does the heavy lifting
            sb.append(list.remove(random.nextInt(list.size())));
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Test the example.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(getRandomString());
    }
}
```

This solution should be efficient as most method calls are constant-time operations, and have approximately 2N running time, where N is the number of Strings to be randomly connected (because of the adds to the ArrayList, and the code in the while loop).

Comment: Thanks but i a germa guy. i think i have false tranlsation. The Output is ok. My Problem is to connect randomly the Keywords that are typed in by User. So i mean in the Input are the Worde Ex1 ex2 and ex3 so now when the user klick button the i will that the Program randomly connect the Words and when all words are connected randomly the generator stop

Comment: Oh sry false commentary box :D Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it was helpful, if you like it you can up-vote it and select it for the answer, unless the answer is incomplete in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple way to randomize your string :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Ass");
list.add("Pet");
list.add("Dog");  
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list);
```